# Error GlobalKey Flutter Detected, How solve?

Tags: flutter

after a few weeks of using Flutter CRUD I was running normally and able to enter the database, but this time I encountered an error as shown below.

[image]

The error appears when I finish editing data, delete data. What do you think the solution to this problem is, friends?

Here I provide a snippet of my source code

**listnasabah.dart**

```
class ListNasabah {
  ApiService apiService;
  ListNasabah({this.apiService});

  void getNasabah() {
    apiService.getNasabah().then((nasabah) {
      print(nasabah);
    });
  }

  Widget createViewList() {
    return SafeArea(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: apiService.getNasabah(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Nasabah>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                'Something wrong with message: ${snapshot.error.toString()}',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            List<Nasabah> nasabah = snapshot.data;
            return nasabahListView(nasabah);
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget nasabahListView(List<Nasabah> listnasabah) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 16.0),
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          Nasabah nasabah = listnasabah[index];
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
            child: Card(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      nasabah.nama_debitur,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                    ),
                    Text(nasabah.alamat),
                    Text(nasabah.no_ktp),
                    Text(nasabah.no_telp),
                    Text(nasabah.no_selular),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ElevatedButton.icon(
                          onPressed: () {
                            showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                                title: Text('Hapus Data Nasabah'),
                                content: Text(
                                    'Apakah anda yakin ingin menghapus data nasabah ini?'),
                                actions: [
                                  TextButton(
                                      child: Text('Yes'),
                                      onPressed: () async {
                                        apiService
                                            .deleteNasabah(nasabah.id)
                                            .then((value) => Navigator.of(
                                                    context)
                                                .pushReplacement(
                                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                                        builder: (context) =>
                                                            DataNasabah())));
                                      })
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: Colors.red,
                          ),
                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                          label: Text('Hapus'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 5,
                        ),
                        ElevatedButton.icon(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => DetailNasabah(
                                  nasabah: nasabah,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
                          label: Text(
                            'Detail',
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: listnasabah.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try hot reload?

Comment: yes, it's been many times @AmateurCoder